# Using std::os::linux and std::os::windows in a cross-platform application

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to create a multi-platform application that accesses the file system, and while I can use `std::fs`, I've found that the OS specific crates simplify the code a bit. So, I wrote up some code using `std::os::windows::fs`, and it worked as expected.

My issue now, is that I want to write code for both Windows and Linux. To do this, I've created separate functions that in theory will use `std::os::windows` and `std::os::linux` respectfully. However when trying to compile *on* Linux *for* Linux, I came across the error that `std::os::windows` was not a recognised crate.

My question is, is there any way for me to either use `std::os::windows` on Linux and vice versa, or only compile specific chunks of code depending on the operating system cargo is used on?

I know this is a bit of a stupid question, considering the fact that I could just write separate modules for different OSes, but I do want to try and contain everything in one module.

My current Code is something along the lines of:

```rust
pub fn run(os: &str, path: &str){
    let files = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap_or_else(|error: std::io::Error| {
        println!("Error: {error}");
        process::exit(1);
    });

    // The 'os' variable is obtained from std::env::consts::OS
    if os == "windows" {
        // Use std::os::windows in the following function
        printDir_win(files);
    } else if os == "linux" {
        // Use std::os::linux in the following function
        printDir_lin(files);
    } else {
        println!("{}OS not recognised: defaulting to std::fs methods{}","\x1b[31m","\x1b[0m");
        printDir(files);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`#[cfg(…)` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) for conditional compilation depending on the target OS. That way the compiler won't try to compile code that targets a different OS:

```
pub fn run(path: &str){
    let files = fs::read_dir(path).unwrap_or_else(|error: std::io::Error| {
        println!("Error: {error}");
        process::exit(1);
    });

    // The 'os' variable is obtained from std::env::consts::OS
    #[cfg (target_os = "windows")]
    {
        // Use std::os::windows in the following function
        use std::os::windows::*;
        printDir_win(files);
    }
    #[cfg (target_os = "linux")]
    {
        // Use std::os::linux in the following function
        use std::os::linux;
        printDir_lin(files);
    }
    #[cfg (not (any (target_os = "windows", target_os = "linux")))]
    {
        println!("{}OS not recognised: defaulting to std::fs methods{}","\x1b[31m","\x1b[0m");
        printDir(files);
    }
}
```

---

Note that from an organization standpoint, it is considered good practice to group your platform-specific code in a module that abstracts the differences behind a common API:

```
#[cfg (target_os = "windows")]
mod platform {
    use std::os::windows::*;
    pub fn print_dir (files: std::fs::ReadDir) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
#[cfg (target_os = "linux")]
mod platform {
    use std::os::linux::*;
    pub fn print_dir (files: std::fs::ReadDir) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
#[cfg (not (any (target_os = "windows", target_os = "linux")))]
mod platform {
    pub fn print_dir (files: std::fs::ReadDir) {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Then the rest of your code doesn't need to check the OS everywhere to know which function to call:

```
pub fn run(path: &str){
    let files = std::fs::read_dir(path).unwrap_or_else(|error: std::io::Error| {
        println!("Error: {error}");
        std::process::exit(1);
    });
    platform::print_dir (files);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f362684ecfd626b4a71bf2b0cf8be52f)

Comment: [`cfg_if`](https://docs.rs/cfg-if/latest/cfg_if/) helps avoid the check for all previously checked OSes in the base case.

Comment: Thank you for your help, both of you. I looked into conditional compiling but I didn't see how it could be used for my purposes, but @Jmb 's example made it very clear. Thank you :>